# CANoe vbs system variable control

Tags: vbscript, canoe

I am developing vbs script to launch CANoe and then readout system variable. I am able to launch CANoe successfully and having problem in reading system variable.
My code is as follow:

```
    Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")
Wscript.Sleep(3000)

If Err.Number Then
    Wscript.Echo "Error in opening config file, quit the script" 
    WScript.Quit
Else
    Wscript.Echo "CAnoe Launched successfully" 
End If

'App.Open (ScriptPath & "\CANoe_VW_T7ACS.cfg")
App.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Wscript.Sleep(3000)
If Err.Number Then
    Wscript.Echo "Error in opening config file, quit the script" 
    WScript.Quit
Else
    Wscript.Echo "CAnoe Config Loaded successfully" 
End If

If App.Configuration.ReadOnly Then
  Wscript.Echo "The configuration is read-only."
Else
  Wscript.Echo "The configuration is writeable."
End If

App.Measurement.Start
WScript.Sleep(5000)
WScript.Sleep(5000)
WScript.Sleep(5000)

Set Measurement = App.Measurement
Wscript.ConnectObject Measurement, "Measurement_"
Set Pedal =  App.CAPL.cclSysVarSetInteger("Relais::Relais_S_C1", 0)
Wscript.Echo Pedal

Set App         = Nothing
Set Measurement  = Nothing
```

The error I am getting at line
Set Pedal =  App.CAPL.cclSysVarSetInteger("Relais::Relais_S_C1", 0)
is,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxomN.png)

what can be the problem ?

Comment: As the error message tells you `App.CAPL` does not provide a method named `cclSysVarSetInteger`. If you would simply open CANoe's documentation you would see that `App.CAPL` only provides `Compile` and `GetFunction`.

Comment: Apart from that trying to call something called cclSysVar**Set**Integer for getting the value of a system variable might not be the best idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CANoe reconnect to instance using com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824643/canoe-reconnect-to-instance-using-com). Please don't re-post questions, instead [edit the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71824643/edit) to have it re-opened if the changes deem it.